# Problems using the Spock wildcard in unit test with Gradle

Tags: groovy, spock

I am using Spock 2.0-M4-groovy-3.0 and Groovy 3.0.7 in Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0). In a unit test I tried to create a Mock like this:

```
1 * mockGoogleCalendarClient.bookTimeSlot(_)
```

where the actual code expects an Object that has a number of fields. I don't care about the object so I want to use the wildcard character.

When this runs I get this:

**Test does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.**

This only happens when I use a wildcard in the test. I've tried to figure this error out but so far I have not. To make progress I added the described method to the test like so:

```
@Override
public Object getProperty(String value)
{
  return new Object()
}
```

Now the test runs but nothing seems to match the wildcard. By chance I set a breakpoint on that method to see what was passed to it if anything and it turned out to be "_". It's as if Spock is asking what the value should be.

Why is the test having this problem in the first place?

Comment: Can you come up with an example that we can run, that shows the issue?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this problem, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You have not shown enough information to identify what is wrong, adding the `getProperty` method is definitely not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

At https://github.com/jeffbrown/toronaga07spock is a working example.

[build.gradle](https://github.com/jeffbrown/toronaga07spock/blob/4e6b2af38922eea053579702ed0de78ba495a48b/build.gradle)

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M4-groovy-3.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

[src/main/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarHelper.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/toronaga07spock/blob/4e6b2af38922eea053579702ed0de78ba495a48b/src/main/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarHelper.groovy)

```
package toronaga07spock

class CalendarHelper {

    CalendarClient client

    void book(String message) {
        client.bookTimeSlot message
    }
}
```

[src/main/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarClient.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/toronaga07spock/blob/4e6b2af38922eea053579702ed0de78ba495a48b/src/main/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarClient.groovy)

```
package toronaga07spock

interface CalendarClient {
    void bookTimeSlot(String s)
}
```

[src/test/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarHelperSpec.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/toronaga07spock/blob/4e6b2af38922eea053579702ed0de78ba495a48b/src/test/groovy/toronaga07spock/CalendarHelperSpec.groovy)

```
package toronaga07spock


import spock.lang.Specification

class CalendarHelperSpec extends Specification {

    def "test a basic mock"() {
        given:
        def helper = new CalendarHelper()
        def mockGoogleCalendarClient = Mock(CalendarClient)
        helper.client = mockGoogleCalendarClient

        when:
        helper.book 'Some Booking Message'

        then:
        1 * mockGoogleCalendarClient.bookTimeSlot(_)
    }
}
```